# Alguém sabe porque está a dar erro neste programa?

Tags: c, array, classificação

```
void ordenar(struct piloto *vetor,int contador_pilotos)
{
    int z,i,x,j; 
    for(x=contador_pilotos-1;x<=1;x--)
    {
        for(i=0;i>x;i++)
        {
            if(strcmp(vetor[i].nome,vetor[i+1].nome)>0)
            {
                strcpy(z,vetor[i].nome);
                strcpy(vetor[i].nome,vetor[i+1].nome);
                strcpy(vetor[i+1].nome,z);
            }
        }
    }
    for(j=0;j<=contador_pilotos;j++)
    {
        printf("%s",vetor[j].nome);
    }
}
```

Comment: Qual é o erro, meu filho?

Comment: simplesmente o programa crasha :/

Comment: até onde eu sei, strcpy utiliza 2 vetores de char como parâmetro, logo essa variável z do tipo int no strcpy(z,vetor[i].nome); deve dar problema

Comment: Perguntado há 13 minutos por user64362. Como é que é isso? Quem é o autor da pergunta?

Comment: @VictorStafusa suicídio prematuro :)

Answer (score 0):

A sua primeira estrutura for, não inicia ou fica em loop infinito.

```
for(x=contador_pilotos-1;x<=1;x--)
```

Pode se perceber que `contador_piloto` poderá ser qualquer valor, > 1 ou < 0. Então:

- Quando `contador_piloto < 0` x irá decrescer para sempre pois será sempre menor ou igual a 1;
- Quando `contador_piloto > 2` x será 2 e quando x <= 1, decrementara de x, mas isso não acontecerá pois x não esta dentro da instrução.

Para corrigir esse erro, deve-se mexer na condição:

```
for(x=contador_pilotos-1;x>0;x--)
// ou
for(x=0;x<contador_pilotos;x++)
```

Outro erro, é a parte de cópia, `z` deve ser um vetor de *Char*. `char z[512]`, então se faz a troca.

```
strcpy(z, vetor[i].nome);
strcpy(vetor[i].nome,vetor[i+1].nome);
strcpy(vetor[i+1].nome,z);
```

De uma olhada em algorítimos de ordenação:
[Ordenação Comp Sort](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comb_sort)